# iOS App deployment without the provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode

My client has 10 iPads and I have the app ready for deployment.

The client might find it very difficult to deploy the app with Xcode using provisioning profiles.

Is there any way we can deploy the app to all devices without the provisioning profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an internal app, then it's probably easiest to just register for the Enterprise Developer Program.  This will let you deploy your app internally, and your users can just go to a url and download it.

This is going to save you a lot of effort when you push updates to your app as well.

[Enterprise Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/)

Answer (score 0):

You can publish to the app store but tell Apple to hold the app until you release it.  Then, once it's approved, you can get 10 promo codes for the version and distribute them to the client with instructions to download the app from the app store.

Not practical if you're getting feedback for ongoing development and testing, but might work if they just need to give final approval before it ships.

Answer (score 0):

The only ways to distribute a development build is to hook the devices up to your development machine and load a build on to them directly (marking them as development devices), or to use ad-hoc provisioning profiles as you say above. (The Enterprise dev program, as mentioned in another answer, still requires a provisioning profile.)

You don't necessarily need Xcode to distribute the build and the profile. You can use iTunes to load both on a device (what I have my clients use) but you can also use the (free) iPhone Configuration Utility ([Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL851), [Win](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL926)) if it suits you (although I've only tried it once myself).

I would not recommend, for numerous reasons, submitting the app to the App Store, as is suggested by another answer.

Answer (score 0):

There a few new ways of doing this wirelessly but for all of them you will need to get the devices UDID and add to your list of authorised devices.

Once that's done, you can package the App up with its provising profile (build and archive) and use one of the wireless distribution methods that have been popping up lately.

All you have to do is point the iPads to a web address via Safari and your client will be prompted to install the App. Doesn't get any easier than that!

I had good experiences with this one but your clients devices will need to be on iOS 4.0+ http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/

Good luck.
Rog